# Image as a flex item not scaling with max-width in Chrome

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, flexbox

I have an image within a flex container.

The image stays at its original height in Chrome and will not resize proportionally. It works in Firefox however.

```
<figure>
 <img src="image.jpg">
 <a href="#">A link to somewhere</a>
</figure>

figure {
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
}

figure img {     
 max-width: 50%;
 height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex makes its children equal in height by default. To disable this behavior, you can specify `align-items: flex-start`.

https://jsfiddle.net/3s2hLv92/1/